# Easy way to control all inputs?

Tags: php

I have in mysql table 98 fields, and I am trying to make all inputs `$_POST` and control it if they are numeric etc.

Is there any easy way to type that or I need make all inputs like this one:

`$age = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['age']));`

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `real_escape_string` use `prepare` instead

Answer (score -1):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

```
$_POST = array_map(function($item){
    return $db->real_escape_string(trim($item));
},$_POST)
```

Answer (score -1):

please provide perfect scenario what you want to do?

if u try to escape all $_POST field than simplay loop $_POST and store back it's value in $_POST appropriate key than you got filter value.

eg.

```
foreach($_POST as &$key => $post){
    $key = $db->real_escape_string(trim($post));
}
```